# Sum of the first 200 numbers in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a block of Clojure code that will calculate the sum of the first 200 integers. The answer I'm trying to get as output is 20100. Here is my closest attempt.

```
(reduce + (range 200))
```

The above code outputs: 19900.

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong here and how to go about solving this?

Answer (score 7):

From `range`'s [doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range):

> Returns a lazy seq of nums from start (inclusive) to end
> **(exclusive)**

BTW, unless you HAVE to use reduce, it would be better to use Gauss's formula:

```
(defn sum-first-n [n]
  (/ (* n (inc n)) 2))
```

Proof:

```
user=> (defn sum-first-n [n]
  #_=>   (/ (* n (inc n)) 2))
#'user/sum-first-n
user=> (sum-first-n 200)
20100
```

Answer (score 7):

Other users have given 2 great solutions to your problem, however I'm not sure they answered "how to go about solving this?".

In a traditional language I'd fire up a debugger and inspect the collection I'm reducing over. In Clojure it's much easier. I'm at the REPL so I can examine things directly.

```
 ;; I always forget how range works after 10 years hacking clj
 (reduce + (range 200))
 ;; => 19900
 ;; that's not what I expect
 (last (range 200))
 ;; => 199
 ;; aha!
 (last (range 201))
 ;; => 200
 (reduce + (range 201))
 ;; => 20100
```

The power of this can't be overestimated. For things which take more effort than generating a range of numbers, you might store the data in a var to inspect it.

```
 (def x (unnecessary-webservice/range 200))
 ;; => #'user/x
 (reduce + x)
 ;; => 19900
 (last x)
 ;; => 199
 ;; etc
```

Answer (score 3):

`(range 200)` generates a sequence from 0 to 199. To get the Sum of integers from 0 to 200, it would be

```
(reduce + (range 201))
```

Comment: (reduce + (range (inc 200)))